# How the kernel gives seg. fault for a scenario like this?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I have a doubt in accessing some invalid data. How can the OS cause a segmentation fault for a scenario like this:

Suppose a chunk of data is 100 bytes long, aligned at the beginning of a 4K page. If we access the valid data within the first 100 bytes of the page, this will load the page into memory, and put the page table entry is in TLB. If we now try to access some invalid data between the 100 and 4K, since the entry is there in page table already, will we be allowed to access the invalid data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. But typically you're not allocating memory directly from the operating. You usually allocate it via some library function (`new` or `malloc`, etc). The library function will take the 4KB (usually it allocates more than 4KB in one chunk, too) and splits it up into the actual chunks that you ask for. So usually when you ask for 100 bytes of memory, that 100 bytes will be "wedged" in between two other allocation requests that you've made.

This is why it's "undefined behaviour" when you access data off the end of an array: you *might* get a segmentation fault, you *might* trash some other variable that happens to be stored there, or you *might* be OK and it actually works (for a while at least).

Answer (score 2):

The entire page belongs to your program, so no segmentation fault or access violation will be generated.  For this reason memory debugging tools such as [Electric Fence](http://directory.fsf.org/project/ElectricFence/) optionally respond to allocation requests with a block of memory at the very end of a page instead of the beginning, so that out of bounds bugs cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

You may, in fact, be able to access the invalid data between bytes 100 and 4K of the page even when the page isn't loaded. The kernel only knows about accesses that are made to a page that's doesn't exist (or to a page where you don't have read/write permission). The exact locations of specific chunks of data on pages is determined by the C library, not by the kernel.

If you want an invalid memory access to fail instantly for debugging purposes, you should use a tool like valgrind, which checks all memory accesses. That's still no guarantee that you'll have an error reported. You might find you're actually accessing a piece of memory that's been allocated for some other purpose, and in this situation valgrind has no way of knowing that it's wrong.